# (wxWidget C++) Save User Input

Tags: c++, user-interface, save, user-input, wxwidgets

I am trying to save user input when the user changes a value on a slider and hits enter, or I can have a text box where the user inputs a number, but this is saved as a string in wxWidget which is a problem because the value needs to be an integer.

The user is presented with this, [Window 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxdmL.png), then this,[Window 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0RcJ.png), where the value I need is inputted...

Here is my code:

```
 using namespace std;

    Frame::Frame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title)
    {

    }

    void Frame::OnButton1(wxCommandEvent&)
    {
    Close();
    Gas Air(1.4, 287);

Frame* Window_Oblique = new Frame("Oblique Shock Calculator");
Window_Oblique->SetClientSize(500, 400);
wxStaticText* Question = new wxStaticText(Window_Oblique, wxID_ANY, "Enter Oblique Shock Mach 1", wxPoint(175, 50));
/*xTextCtrl* textCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(Window_Oblique, wxID_ANY, "Enter Mach 1", wxPoint(150, 100), wxSize(200, -1));*/
wxSpinCtrl* spinCtrl = new wxSpinCtrl(Window_Oblique, wxID_ANY, "", wxPoint(200, 100), wxSize(50, -1));
wxButton* Button5 = new wxButton(Window_Oblique, 5, "Enter", wxPoint(250, 101), wxSize(35, 20));
    int MachNumber1_normalShock = spinCtrl->GetValue();
    NormalShock normShock1;

    normShock1.setGamma(Air.getGamma());
    normShock1.setGasConstant(Air.getGasConstant());
    normShock1.setMachNumber1(MachNumber1_normalShock);

    normShock1.calculatePressureRatio();
    cout << normShock1.getPressureRatio() << endl;

    normShock1.calculateDensityRatio();
    cout << normShock1.getDensityRatio() << endl;

    normShock1.calculateTemperatureRatio();
    cout << normShock1.getTemperatureRatio() << endl;

    normShock1.calculateMachNumber2();
    cout << normShock1.getMachNumber2() << endl;

    Window_Oblique->Show();
    
    }

    void Frame::OnButton2(wxCommandEvent&)
    {
Close();
Frame* Window_Normal = new Frame("Normal Shock Calculator");
Window_Normal->SetClientSize(500, 400);
wxStaticText* Question = new wxStaticText(Window_Normal, wxID_ANY, "Enter Normal Shock Details", wxPoint(250, 50));
Window_Normal->Show();
    }

    void Frame::OnButton3(wxCommandEvent&)
    {
Close();
Frame* Window_Isen = new Frame("Isentropic Flow Calculator");
Window_Isen->SetClientSize(500, 400);
wxStaticText* Question = new wxStaticText(Window_Isen, wxID_ANY, "Enter Isnetropic Flow Details", wxPoint(130, 50));
Window_Isen->Show();
    }

    void Frame::OnButton4(wxCommandEvent&)
    {
Close();
Frame* Window_Expansion = new Frame("Expansion Fan Calculator");
Window_Expansion->SetClientSize(500, 400);
wxStaticText* Question = new wxStaticText(Window_Expansion, wxID_ANY, "Enter Expansion Fan  Details", wxPoint(130, 50));
Window_Expansion->Show();
    }

    void Frame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent&)
    {
Close();
    }

    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(Frame, wxFrame)
    EVT_BUTTON(1, Frame::OnButton1)
    EVT_BUTTON(2, Frame::OnButton2)
    EVT_BUTTON(3, Frame::OnButton3)
    EVT_BUTTON(4, Frame::OnButton4)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_EXIT, Frame::OnQuit)
    END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

'''

Comment: did you see this: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString#wxString_to_integer_number

Comment: in addition - why does it have to be an integer and not a string? After all its just a set of characters and only our mind interpret them as integer number....

Comment: @Igor Basically I just wanted a double because the value is going to be used in setter and getter functions for various different problem types. My current issue figuring out a way to use cout for all my values since wxWidget does do consol output when running a window...